# Symfony 5 guard authentication system and API key generation

Tags: symfony

I am using guard authentication for a new API. It is based on the documentation in this page https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html.
Does Symfony provide a built-in method to generate new API keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use LexikJWT bundle for, You can use following to generate and validate in API

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#usage